# Error running Win10 Docker container in Windows KVM instance

Tags: windows, docker, kvm

I'm trying to run a Windows 10 Pro Docker container (mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903) in a Windows 10 Pro KVM instance running Proxmox VE 5.3-11 on Debian 9.8

The command I'm running is this:

docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903

The response is this:

"docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 429fddc1aac583fa38447054b3f0392d1f2223e62d12d5c7fbfc3f2f14566527: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed."

I would appreciate any help solving the problem.  Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Thanks.

QEMU/KVM version 5

The docker versions are:

Desktop:  2.1.0.0 (36874)

Channel Stable

Engine 19.03.1

Compose 1.24.1

Kubernetes v1.14.3

Note 0.6.1

Credential Helpers 0.6.3

Machine 0.16.1

I have tried several different Docker containers, the most recent one (in my question) is the official microsoft container.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to activate nested virtualization? 
https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Nested_Virtualization

Comment: For any other KVM: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-nested-virtualization-in-kvm/